# Convert the time string received from server to local time

Tags: android, datetime, mysqli

Users post messages to my server which are stored in database with one column being CURRENT_TIMESTAMP by default. Like below:

```
Message Table:

Sender |  Content |  SentTime 

Tom    | hi there | 2013-06-19 00:13:21
```

When user post messages to my server, he/she doesn't need to post his/her local time. My database record that value automatically. I feel it's better than having user post his/her time together with message.

Later user will retrieve the message from the server as well as sent time. I'm wondering how to convert that time into user's local time.

I'm using Json to encode on server then decode data in my app. So the time get from server will be a string like: `2013-06-19 00:13:21` I guess I need to parse this string to start with?

Comment: you need the time in milliseconds?

Comment: not only do you need to set the right format using `Locale`, but you also need to know something about what time zone the user is in. How does the server handle this?

Comment: @Phil I don't think server need to know it, it can just record the time of a particular time zone, say EST. Then when it's returned to user's phone. I can get the local time zone of the phone and fix the time I get from server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to parse the String returned by the server with SimpeDateFormat:

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"));
Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse("2013-06-19 00:13:21");

TimeZone destTz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("yourtimezone");
simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(destTz);
String result = simpleDateFormat.format(date);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't follow why I need ms? Also from here how do I change it to user's local time?

Comment: I need to convert this time to user's local time. Because the user can be in UK, French in different time zones...

Comment: does the server stores the date in utc?

Comment: No it's EST. Should I change it?

Comment: Oh..I'm sorry, it's actually `Central Standard Time`

Comment: change the timezone from EST to CST

Comment: for that "yourtimezone", I should use `TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();tz.getDisplayName(false,TimeZone.SHORT); ` to get it right?

Comment: yes `TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault(); simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(tz);`

Comment: It's weird. CST doesn't work right. The value converted seems to be from GMT. So I tried to debug with `String abc = TimeZone.getTimeZone("CST").toString();System.out.println("CST:"+abc);` and get this:
06-21 14:40:30.683: I/System.out(19404): CST:java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=GMT,offset=0,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=false,startYear=0,startMode=0,startMonth=0,startDay=0,startDayOfWeek=0,startTime=0,endMode=0,endMonth=0,endDay=0,endDayOfWeek=0,endTime=0]

Comment: @Blackbelt my time format is "`h:mm a`" and date format is "`EEE, MMM d`". How can I convert this into user's local time and date?